# Using jq to build another json object with this string

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, packer

Currently I am using packer to copy AWS AMIs to multiple regions and then spitting out the AMI IDs using Packer's post processor: https://packer.io/docs/post-processors/manifest.html.

Here is a sample of the output:

```
{
  "name": "amazon-ebs",
  "builder_type": "amazon-ebs",
  "build_time": 1584037532,
  "files": null,
  "artifact_id": "ca-central-1:ami-02420*,us-east-1:ami-06a4*,us-west-1:ami-078cf*",
  "packer_run_uuid": "",
  "custom_data": null
}
```

I'd like to use jq to be able to build a new json in this format:

```
{
  "ca-central": "ami_id",
  "us-east-1": "ami_id",
  "us-west-1": "ami_id"
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me with the jq command to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your input, the following jq program:

```
.artifact_id
| [ split(",")[] 
    | (split(":") | {(.[0]): .[1] } ) ]
| add
```

produces:

```
{
  "ca-central-1": "ami-02420*",
  "us-east-1": "ami-06a4*",
  "us-west-1": "ami-078cf*"
}
```

Comment: Could you write this as a jq one-liner so that I can dissect and study it (I've only worked with jq as one-liners on the command line)? Or possibly explain it, thank you for taking the time out to help me :)

Comment: You can string together the lines if you really want to, but I'd recommend using the -f command-line option.

Comment: Thanks so much peak, 

I've chosen your answer as it works great! Hoping you can help me disect this a bit. Since I am using this jq command in a pipeline, I prefer a one liner than injecting a file into the container. This worked great:
`cat manifest.json | jq '.builds[0].artifact_id | [split(",")[] | (split(":") | {(.[0]): .[1] } )] | add'`

1. First you're splitting by the comma, what is that [] after the split doing? 

To be quite honest I don't understand the rest

Comment: split(",")[] produces a stream of the strings; you could write splits(",") instead.